# Gitlab CI/CD not accepting public key

Tags: ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci

**Local Setup**

I created a public and private SSH key via the ssh-keygen command.

I successfully communicated with the server using the same public key from another laptop.

**GitLab CI Setup**

I then decided to setup the private key and communication on gitlab CI.

Inside my repo, I navigated to Settings -> Continuous Integration -> Variables, and added the following environment variables:

- $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY - I used the same private key that I used locally

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "main" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "merge_request_event"      
      when: never
    - when: always

stages:
  - test
  - build
  - deploy

run_unit_tests:
  image: node:17-alpine3.16.2
  stage: test
  tags:
    - johnlap-fedora-shell
  before_script:
    - cd app
    - npm install
  script:
    - npm run test
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - app/junit.xml
    reports:
      junit:
        - app/junit.xml

variables:
  IMAGE_NAME: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE
  IMAGE_TAG: "1.0"
  DEV_SERVER_HOST: ?.?.?.?

build_image:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - johnlap-fedora-shell
  before_script:
    # - echo "Linux user is $USER"
    # - echo "Docker registry user is $CI_REGISTRY_USER"
    # - echo "Docker registry name is $CI_REGISTRY"
    # - echo "Docker registry image is $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE"
  script:
    # - docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/?/mynodeapp-cicd-project:1.0 .
    # - docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/microservice/payment:1.0 .
    - docker build -t $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG .

push_image:
  stage: build
  needs:
    - build_image
  tags:
    - johnlap-fedora-shell
  before_script:
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    # - docker push registry.gitlab.com/?/mynodeapp-cicd-project:1.0
#      - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/microservice/payment:1.0
    - docker push $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG

deploy_to_dev:
  stage: deploy
  tags: 
    - johnlap-fedora-shell
  before_script:
    - chmod 644 $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
  script:
    - ssh -v -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY pala@$DEV_SERVER_HOST "
        docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY &&
        docker run -d -p 3000:3000 $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG"
```

**Output of job**

```
Running with gitlab-runner 15.4.0 (43b2dc3d)
  on johnlap-fedora-shell FCNMb4yU
Preparing the "shell" executor
00:00
Using Shell executor...
Preparing environment
00:01
Running on fedora...
Getting source from Git repository
00:01
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/gitlab-runner/builds/FCNMb4yU/0/?/mynodeapp-cicd-project/.git/
Checking out 105f1987 as main...
Removing app/junit.xml
Skipping Git submodules setup
Downloading artifacts
00:01
Downloading artifacts for run_unit_tests (3199528349)...
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=27228 revision=43b2dc3d version=15.4.0
Downloading artifacts from coordinator... ok        id=3199528349 responseStatus=200 OK token=r4U5kiaw
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:01
$ chmod 644 $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
$ ssh -v -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY pala@$DEV_SERVER_HOST " docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY && docker run -d -p 3000:3000 $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG"
OpenSSH_8.8p1, OpenSSL 3.0.5 5 Jul 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug1: configuration requests final Match pass
debug1: re-parsing configuration
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug1: Connecting to ?.?.?.? port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/gitlab-runner/builds/FCNMb4yU/0/?/mynodeapp-cicd-project.tmp/SSH_PRIVATE_KEY type 3
debug1: identity file /home/gitlab-runner/builds/FCNMb4yU/0/?/mynodeapp-cicd-project.tmp/SSH_PRIVATE_KEY-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.8 FreeBSD-openssh-portable-8.8.p1_1,1
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.8 FreeBSD-openssh-portable-8.8.p1_1,1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to ?.?.?.?:22 as 'pala'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes256-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes256-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=32 dh_need=32
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=32 dh_need=32
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:SSH_PRIVATE_KEY-HERE
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host '?.?.?.?' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/gitlab-runner/builds/FCNMb4yU/0/?/mynodeapp-cicd-project.tmp/SSH_PRIVATE_KEY ED25519 SHA256:PRIVATEKEYHERE explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/gitlab-runner/builds/FCNMb4yU/0/?/mynodeapp-cicd-project.tmp/SSH_PRIVATE_KEY ED25519 SHA256:PRIVATEKEYHERE explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
Received disconnect from ?.?.?.? port 22:2: Too many authentication failures
Disconnected from ?.?.?.? port 22
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

This line indicates that it found the private key:

```
debug1: Found key in /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/known_hosts:1
```

These line indicates that it's trying to communicate with the terminal using the /dev/tty file. Of course, this script is running in a non-interactive manor so it fails. Shouldn't it be using my key instead of requesting a passphrase from the terminal?
There must be something wrong with the private/public key.

```
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive

debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty
```

Comment: Is your private key passphrase protected? If yes, did you try with one created without  passphrase?

Comment: According to the debug output, ssh offered the key in /home/gitlab-runner/builds/FCNMb4yU/0/?/mynodeapp-cicd-project.tmp/SSH_PRIVATE_KEY to the server and the server didn't accept it. All of the lines about /dev/tty are just ssh falling back to a form of password authentication after running out of keys to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for the help. In the end I installed the gitlab runner in an EC2 instance which resolved the issue